# Undefined vector name error in python script

Tags: python, vector, allocation

I am trying to do these two operations in python. I know the length of L 
vector which is equal to n1 and length of R which is equal to n2.
Also, p and q are some constants.

```
for i in range (0,n1):
    L[i]=a[p+i-1]

for j in range (0,n2):
    R[j]=a[q+j]
```

I am getting an error that says `"Namerror: name 'L' is not defined"`. So essentially, i have to allocate the length of L and R which i don't know how to do in Python.

Comment: To allocate, do `L = [0]*n1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your list before start the loops.

```
L = [0]*n1
L = [0]*n2
for i in range (0,n1): L[i]=a[p+i-1]

for j in range (0,n2): R[j]=a[q+j]
```

Answer (score 0):

To allocate, do `L = [0] * n1`. But this is best done using generator expressions:

```
L = list(a[p+i-1] for i in range (n1))
```